# Can 802.1Q VLAN packets be passed through Wi-Fi transparently?

Tags: wireless-networking, vlan

I'd like to reduce some wires. But my TV box requires both Internet connection with Ethernet and IPTV broadcast signal within VLAN. So I have to pass plain Ethernet packets and VLAN packets with Wi-Fi, if I don't want another more device which mixes them at the TV box.

I need to plan and buy some new devices. Anyone knows whether a standard Wi-Fi AP transfers 802.1Q VLAN packets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because VLAN support is not a common requirement for home 802.11 gear, and because the Wi-Fi certification program doesn't test it, you'll probably find that a lot of consumer gear doesn't support it or has showstopper bugs. Especially when sending a full-size 1500 byte frame that's VLAN tagged, as the VLAN tag makes the frame a few bytes longer than the usual maximum sized frame.

You'll probably either have to test it for yourself on whatever gear you buy, or ask around to find others who have found solutions that work.

Answer (score 3):

No WiFi gear supports 802.1q/VLAN tagging over the air, not even enterprise grade stuff.  802.11 mac layer doesnt have support for the insertion of a vlan tag.  Any solution that can support vlan tagging would be completely proprietary, I havent noted any yet and have been looking for a soluton to the same issue.

Comment: So are you saying that there is no solution, or just that you haven’t found one?  It’s hard to prove universal negatives (e.g., no unicorns exist, *anywhere*).  If you saying that there is no solution, can you back that up with a reference?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about "standard" APs but I've had good luck in the past using tagged VLANs on DD-WRT  and also Ubiquiti APs.